# Disallow URLs with empty parameters in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Normally I have this URL structure:

```
http://example.com/team/name/16356**
```

But sometimes my CMS generates URLs without name:

```
http://example./com/team//16356**
```

and then it’s **404**.

How to disavow such URLs when they are empty?

Probably it would be possible with regex for empty symbol here, but I dont want to mess up with Googlebot, better do good from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block URLs like `http://example./com/team//16356**`, where the number part can be different, you could use the following robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /team//
```

This will block crawling of any URL whose path starts with `/team//`.